# An active access token must be used to query information about the current user in laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, facebook, laravel

I am trying to login with facebook using angularjs with laravel. But I am stuck with this error:

> {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query
>   information about the current user.","type":"OAuthExce (truncated...)

Here is my Controller:

```
 public function facebookLogin(Request $request){
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $params = [
            'code' => $request->input('code'),
            'client_id' => $request->input('clientId'),
            'redirect_uri' => $request->input('redirectUri'),
            'client_secret' => Config::get('app.facebook_secret'),
            'grant_type'=>'client_credentials'
        ];

        // Step 1. Exchange authorization code for access token.
        $accessTokenResponse = $client->request('GET', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/oauth/access_token', [
            'query' => $params
        ]);


        $accessToken = json_decode($accessTokenResponse->getBody(), true);

        // Step 2. Retrieve profile information about the current user.
        $fields = 'id,email,first_name,last_name,link,name,picture';
        /**** problem counted with this request ************/
        $profileResponse = $client->request('GET', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me', [
            'query' => [
                'access_token' => $accessToken['access_token'],
                'fields' => $fields
            ]
        ]);

        $profile = json_decode($profileResponse->getBody(), true);

        $user = User::where('email', '=', $profile['email'])->first();

        if($user) {
            Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
            $user_info = Auth::user();
            $profile_seen = $user_info->profile_seen;
            User::where('id', '=', $user_info->id)->update(array('profile_seen' => 1));
            return Response::json(['login' => Auth::check(),'profile_seen' => $profile_seen ]);

        }else{

            $user = User::create(array(
                                        'username'   => $profile['name'], 
                                        'email'      => $profile['email'],
                                        'first_name' => $profile['first_name'],
                                        'last_name'  => $profile['last_name'],
                                        'facebook_id'=> $profile['id']
                                       ));

            Auth::loginUsingId($user->id,1);
            $user_info = Auth::user();
            $profile_seen = $user_info->profile_seen;
            User::where('id', '=', $user_info->id)->update(array('profile_seen' => 1));
            return Response::json(['login' => Auth::check(),'profile_seen' => $profile_seen ]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: well, did you debug the access token? do you get a valid one?

Comment: Yes I checked it @luschn

Comment: are you sure it´s a valid user token? the error message is very clear.

Comment: @Deepaksaini did you verify your `$params`? Is the `client_id` correct? `var_dump($params); var_dump($accessToken); die;`.

Comment: did you debug it here? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this problem. You need to run the `composer update`. Then run the command `composer dump-autoload`. This problem has been fixed in version Socialite v2.0.21.